# End a function inside another function without affect the main function in php

Tags: php, function

I have a main function, inside it there is another function which heavily relates on several functions. I need to terminate the second function whenever some criteria meet. This, by itself, comes from the result of those, let's say, inner functions. So, how can I terminate only the second function that doesn't affect the main function being running. I'm aware of `die` and `exit`. however, those two, terminate the whole process.

```
function main($string) {
   //some code here...

     function second($content) {
        //more code...

        inner_one($evaluate);
        //need to stop second function if some criteria met here, but the rest of the "main function" should run normally
     }

  //more codes...

}

function inner_one($evaluate) {
  //some evaluation here
  //the result of this function should make "second function" stop or allow running
}
```

If I use `die` or `exit` inside inner function the whole process fail. How to get that to work?

Comment: `die` or `exit`   will exit your program. Use `return;` if you want to continue;

Comment: `return` only stop the "inner function" not the "second function"

Comment: If you check immediately for the result of first and return from the second is also an option. I would prefer [throwing an exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), however, and catch it somewhere where is needed, maybe two, three or more functions above.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you will get idea from here.

```
function main($string) {
    //some code here...

    function second($content) {
         //more codes
         $status=inner_one($evaluate);
         if(!$status)//if your inner_one does not run successfully return false
         {
              return false;
         }
         //write your other codes for second
         //return false if it gets any error
         //more codes
          return true;            
    }

    //more codes...

}

function inner_one($evaluate) {
    //your codes going here
    //if you find some error return false

    ///         ............
    return true;//at the end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should probably take out your `second` function to make it an external one. Then use `return` on your inner functions. `die` and `exit` are fairly uncommonly needed. Typically only for error handling and such when your entire application does need to come to a complete halt.

For this specific code though, you should add a return value that you check if you need to exit.

Comment: In your case it's true, but please consider here I have _three_ functions and I need to stop the "second function" based on the values of the inner functionS (which for simplicity I've put only one, inner_one), but want to allow the "main" one to run in spite of the "second function"

Answer (score 0):

Recall that when you write:

```
function foo(){
  // code....
}
```

You *define* function `foo`. This function will not be executed unless *called*, which may be written in different fashions.
 Either directly:

```
 foo();
```

Or by using existing functions of PHP (`call_user_func`), or by assigning the name of the function to a variable and using that variable as the function:

```
$fun = 'foo';
$fun(); // calls foo
```

Function definitions may occur anywhere in PHP code where a statement is valid. That means that `second` as written in your code snippet is a function definition, which will be visible from any other place in the program. The subtle point is that this definition will only be *enabled* when `main` is being executed<sup>(*)</sup>, as opposed to having that function definition at global scope (outside of any other function or class).

Although this a quite powerful feature, unless you want to make sure that `main` is being executed before making `second` available, or if you want to pick one definition at runtime among several definitions of `second`, I suggest to avoid putting function definitions inside other function definitions.

Now, when you call `second`, your function will behave as any other regular PHP function, so simply use `return` to signify that you want the execution flow to leave the function (ie. that the PHP interpreter exits the function and keeps running to the next instruction after the call to `second`).

`exit` and `die` are indeed instructions interrupting the PHP script execution, and may be used anywhere an instruction is valid.

A simple way to implement your requirements is to have `inner_one` return a value which may be interpreted as a boolean — the simplest is to use a boolean directly of course:

```
function inner_one($evaluate){
  // some computation yielding $some_state 
  if ($some_state == SOME_GOOD_VALUE)
    return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Or more effectively :

```
function inner_one($evaluate){
  // some computation
  return ($some_state == SOME_GOOD_VALUE);
}
```

`second` may then act accordingly to that returned value, by following a similar algorithm:

```
function second(){
  // some computation
  if (inner_one($evaluate)){
    // carry on computation
  }
}
```

Or, to avoid too many code nestings:

```
function second(){
  // some computation 
  if (!inner_one($evaluate)) 
    return ;
  // carry on computation 
}
```

---

<sup>(*) to be precise, any definition is enabled as soon as the execution flow has evaluated it, which explains why you may write functions inside others and have this neat mechanism</sup>